# Prove $\forall \alpha >2\, (\alpha+\alpha)<\alpha \cdot\alpha <\alpha^\alpha$

Tags: set-theory, proof-explanation, ordinals

Prove $\forall \alpha >2: (\alpha+\alpha)<\alpha \cdot\alpha <\alpha^\alpha$ where $*$ is ordinal multiplication.

Attempt: Proof by induction on $\alpha$, so for the base case let $\alpha=3$ then $\alpha+\alpha=3+3<\alpha\cdot\alpha=9<\alpha^{\alpha}=27$ Hence the case when $\alpha=3$ holds.

Now let $\alpha$ be a successor, then $\alpha=S(\beta)$ then $\alpha+\alpha=S(\beta)+S(\beta)=S(\beta+\beta)<\alpha\cdot\alpha=S(\beta)*S(\beta)=s(\beta\cdot\beta)
<\alpha^{\alpha}=S(\beta)^{S(\beta)}=S(\beta^{\beta})$ so the case when $\alpha$ is a successor holds

Now let $\alpha$ be a limit ordinal, then $\alpha+\alpha=\sup_{\lambda<\alpha}(\lambda+\lambda)<\alpha\cdot\alpha=\sup_{\lambda<\alpha}(\lambda\cdot\lambda)<\alpha^{\alpha}=\sup_{\lambda<\alpha}(\lambda^{\lambda})$

So the case when $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal holds,

Thus $\forall \alpha>2:(\alpha+\alpha)<\alpha\cdot\alpha<\alpha^{\alpha}$

I doubt this is correct as i got stuck with the successor and limit steps, any further help would be gratefully appreciated. I haven't done transfinite induction for a while so that might be why

Comment: Induction works... So why don't you begin your proof and show us how far you've come and where you got stuck?

Comment: Brilliant, i will edit my post

Comment: I have added my attempt on here

Comment: That's not a proof - you've just spelled out the claim in more detail. Why is $S(\beta + \beta) < \alpha * \alpha$?

Comment: Also $S(\beta)+S(\beta) \neq S(\beta + \beta)$.  You need another $S$ on the right.  The multiplication repeats the error, but it is not so easy to fix.

Comment: okay, so is my attempt at when $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal correct? & i'm not sure how to fix the successor case

Comment: I don't see how induction will let you pass the $\omega$the step. What you write is grossly incorrect.

Comment: What would you recommend @AsafKaragila

Comment: Rewrite. $\alpha+\alpha=\alpha\cdot 2$. Similarly the multiplication is just $\alpha^2$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila i've wrote them as that, how would i deal with the $\alpha^{\alpha}$ term? and would i use induction on these when they have been rewritten? would you be able to provide a solution?

Comment: I'm really confused with this, i've been learning this for my dissertation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\alpha+\alpha=\alpha\cdot2$ and $\alpha\cdot\alpha=\alpha^2$.

To prove the result, show that if we fix $\alpha>2$, then for all $\beta<\gamma$:

1. $\alpha\cdot\beta<\alpha\cdot\gamma$, and
2. $\alpha^\beta<\alpha^\gamma$.

Then apply this to the specific case that $\beta=2$ and $\gamma=\alpha$.

Comment: This makes much more sense now i had already proven the results one and two here, it was in a book i was studying, i proved them by using transfinite induction on $\alpha$. My question is now, why do we restrict $\gamma$ like this, surely it would hold regardless assuming $\gamma>\beta$ i don't see why it needs to be bounded by $\alpha$

Comment: No, you're right. I was confusing myself with something else.